# How to async fetch data in useEffect

Tags: reactjs, async-await, use-effect, use-state

I have some issue. When I do to async fetch data (using axios for fetching) in the useEffect, and after I set responsed data to state, using a useState hook. And page render befor then I got response from server.
For demonstration this issue I have putted console.log for get current state, and I get 'undefined':

```
const [positions, setPositions] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    const fetchPositions = async () => {
        const response = await EmployeeService.getEmployeePositions();
        setPositions(response.data);
    };
    
    fetchPositions();
    console.log('positions from state: ', positions); //undefined
}, []);
```

Method for fetching data from "EmployeeService":

```
getEmployeePositions(){
    return axios.get(EMPLOYEE_API_BASE_URL + '/positions');
}
```

Thanks in advance, and best regards!

Comment: that console.log would never log the result given that the result doesn't exist until the async function is done. `undefined` is the correct and expected result.

Comment: note that `setPositions` doesn't have immediate effect so it can be undefined https://stackoverflow.com/a/54069332/507203

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React needs to re-render to display the results.
Which means you need to capture the result on the subsequent re-render that is caused when you setState.
Move the console log outside of the useEffect

```
const [positions, setPositions] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    const fetchPositions = async () => {
        const response = await EmployeeService.getEmployeePositions();
        setPositions(response.data);
    };

    fetchPositions();
}, []);

console.log('positions from state: ', positions); // NOT UNDEFINED
```

React will always render once before you have data.
So you can catch it with a condition.

```
if (positions.length === 0) {
   return null;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

nothing wrong with your code, useEffect is always undefined because it read the first value of your rendered app.
To update state in useEffect put paramater on the array [] but in your case it will cause an infinity loop.

try logging inside the async function instead

```js
const [positions, setPositions] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    const fetchPositions = async () => {
        const response = await EmployeeService.getEmployeePositions();
        setPositions(response.data);
        console.log('data from response: ', response);
    };
    
    fetchPositions();
    
}, []);
```

or do it like this

```js
const [positions, setPositions] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    const fetchPositions = async () => {
        const response = await EmployeeService.getEmployeePositions();
        setPositions(response.data);
        console.log('data from response: ', response);
    };

    if((positions ?? []).length == 0){
    fetchPositions();
    console.log('this is position state before fetch~>',positions)
    } else{
    console.log('this is position state after fetch~>',positions)
    }
}, [positions]);
```